# Animate based on dimensions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to animate a composable based on a fixed value and the **$width** of the composable.
How can I get the **$width** to use it for the animate function?
This is my code

```
@Composable
fun ExpandingCircle() {
    val (checked, setChecked) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val radius = if (checked) **$width** else 4.dp
    val radiusAnimated = animate(radius)
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .clickable(onClick = { setChecked(!checked) }),
        onDraw = {
            drawCircle(color = Color.Black, radius = radiusAnimated.toPx())
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I don't need the width already for animate, but i can just use a animated / interpolating float to use it for the calculation in the DrawScope

```
@Composable
fun ExpandingCircle() {
    val (checked, setChecked) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val radiusExpandFactor = if (checked) 1f else 0f
    val radiusExpandFactorAnimated = animate(radiusExpandFactor)
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .clickable(onClick = { setChecked(!checked) }),
        onDraw = {
            val radius = 4.dp.toPx() + (radiusExpandFactorAnimated * (size.width / 2 - 4.dp.toPx()))
            drawCircle(color = Color.Black, radius = radius)
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get the size from `DrawScope`, from the size we can get the width and height of the Canvas, So you can do animation like this.

```
@Composable
fun ExpandingCircle() {
    val (checked, setChecked) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val unCheckedRadius = 4.dp
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .clickable(onClick = { setChecked(!checked) }),
        onDraw = {
            val width = size.width
            drawCircle(color = Color.Black, radius = if (checked) width/2 else unCheckedRadius.toPx())
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: This would not animate between the values would it?